Azure API Management: retrieve backend URL by backend ID
The context is Azure API Management policies.
Knowing the id of a configured backend, how to dynamically retrieve its url?
For exemple:
<set-variable name="mybackend" value="@( GetBackendUrl("myid")  )" />

What should replace the pseudo function "GetBackendUrl"?

Do you want to retrieve the value of backend url configured in APIM?

@IkhtesamAfrin yes

Backend related details gets evaluated in Backend  section of APIM policy including set-backend-service. Therefore, it is not feasible to read the value of backend Url in inbound section.
Alternatively, you can fetch the backend Url in outbound processing using <set-variable  name="mybackend"  value="@(context.Request.Url.ToString())"  />.
I have used the below policy to fetch the backend url configured in the APIM.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="mybackend" value="@(context.Request.Url.ToString())" />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

Trace -

